# Pandas. Python. Заполнить столбцы согласно условию. Сортировка

Tags: python, сортировка, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет. Изучаю Pandas. Не могу никак решить следующую проблему:
Есть DataFrame объект:

```
timeframe  action  result  price
1 минута     BUY    None    100
1 минута     SELL    None    200               
15 минут     BUY    None    110                      
1 час       HOLD    None    100                        
4 часа      HOLD    100     100                        
1 день      HOLD    None    230                        
1 месяц     BUY    None    250                        
1 месяц     SELL    None    240
```

**Внимание задача**: Заполнить пустые ячейки столбца result для строк, где action == SELL , согласно формуле ((sell_price - buy_price) / buy_price ) * 100 (прибыль в процентах от сделки если простыми словами), где sell_price и buy_price имеют одинаковое значение timeframe. А если таковых совпадений нет то все остается без изменений.

```
#Моя попытка прибраться в данных
df = df[df.action != 'HOLD'][df.result.isna() == True][df.timeframe.duplicated(keep=False) == True]
```

*Я пытался двигаться в таком направлении но очень уж мало опыта и понимания Pandas пожалуйста выручайте, и большое спасибо заранее! =))*

**На выходе должно получиться:**

```
    timeframe   action  result  price
    1 минута     BUY    None    100
    1 минута     SELL   100.0   200               
    15 минут     BUY    None    110                      
    1 час       HOLD    None    100                        
    4 часа      HOLD    100     100                        
    1 день      HOLD    None    230                        
    1 месяц     BUY     None    250                        
    1 месяц     SELL    -4.0    240
```

Comment: а как быть если `timeframe` совпадает для более чем двух строк? Кстати в вашем тестовом наборе данных ни одного совпадения нет: `'1 минута' != '1 минут'`...

Comment: @MaxU Привет! Очень надеялся что именно Вы ответите, вы для меня вообще Pandas открыли, можно сказать =) Больше чем двух(или правильнее сказать больше одного) совпадений по одному значению timeframe не будет. Это предусмотренно заранее. 
Исправил опечатку в примере. Там первая и вторая строчка одинаковые значения timeframe  -  1 минута

Comment: @MaxU Но могут быть совпадения для разных таймфреймов - например при очередном цикле могут появится df.action == 'BUY' и df.action == 'SELL' пары сразу на двух таймфреймах(или более) и тогда нужно заполнять result для df.action == 'SELL' согласно формуле...
Пожалуйста выручайте. Такое вот не тривиальное задание я на свою голову организовал. Уже двое суток ломаю голову над Pandasom и данными...))

Comment: @MaxU Добавил максимально сложный пример. И добавил как должно получится на выходе. Извините, что сразу не сделал этого....)

Comment: @MaxU это результат применения формулы result = ((sell_price - buy_price) / buy_price ) * 100.

result = ((240- 250) / 250) * 100 = -4.0. Суть в том что все должно отталкиваться в первую очередь от одинакового timeframe. Если timeframe для строк разный, то это, вообще разные данные и не должны никак между собой сравниваться =)

Comment: @MaxU Господи простите за не внимательность....Конечно же там BUY Я хотел написать. Сегодня я не в меру не внимателен.

Comment: @MaxU Не передать словами, как Вы помогли! Сейчас буду с большой радостью разбираться! Огромнейшее спасибо, как всегда!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала заменим `None` на `NaN` (другими словами - преобразуем столбец `result` в числовой тип данных):

```
df['result'] = pd.to_numeric(df['result'], errors='coerce')

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
  timeframe action  result  price
0  1 минута    BUY     NaN    100
1  1 минута   SELL     NaN    200
2  15 минут    BUY     NaN    110
3     1 час   HOLD     NaN    100
4    4 часа   HOLD   100.0    100
5    1 день   HOLD     NaN    230
6   1 месяц    BUY     NaN    250
7   1 месяц   SELL     NaN    240
```

теперь создадим вспомогательный DataFrame, так чтобы вся необходимая для вычислений информация присутствовала в одной строке и посчитаем `result` по формуле:

```
x = (df[df['action']=='SELL'].reset_index()
       .merge(df.loc[df['action']=='BUY', ['timeframe','action','price']],
              on='timeframe', suffixes=['_sell','_buy'])
       .eval("result = (price_sell / price_buy - 1) * 100")
       .set_index('index'))
```

получилось:

```
In [72]: x
Out[72]:
      timeframe action_sell  result  price_sell action_buy  price_buy
index
1      1 минута        SELL   100.0         200        BUY        100
7       1 месяц        SELL    -4.0         240        BUY        250
```

теперь можно просто заполнить пропущенные значения (Pandas сам найдет нужные строки по совпадаюшим значениям индекса):

```
df['result'] = df['result'].fillna(x['result'])
```

результат:

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
  timeframe action  result  price
0  1 минута    BUY     NaN    100
1  1 минута   SELL   100.0    200
2  15 минут    BUY     NaN    110
3     1 час   HOLD     NaN    100
4    4 часа   HOLD   100.0    100
5    1 день   HOLD     NaN    230
6   1 месяц    BUY     NaN    250
7   1 месяц   SELL    -4.0    240
```

---

некоторые пояснения - пошаговое создание `x` DataFrame:

```
In [81]: df[df['action']=='SELL'].reset_index()
Out[81]:
   index timeframe action result  price
0      1  1 минута   SELL   None    200
1      7   1 месяц   SELL   None    240

In [82]: (df[df['action']=='SELL'].reset_index()
    ...:        .merge(df.loc[df['action']=='BUY', ['timeframe','action','price']],
    ...:               on='timeframe', suffixes=['_sell','_buy']))
    ...:
    ...:
Out[82]:
   index timeframe action_sell result  price_sell action_buy  price_buy
0      1  1 минута        SELL   None         200        BUY        100
1      7   1 месяц        SELL   None         240        BUY        250

In [83]: (df[df['action']=='SELL'].reset_index()
    ...:        .merge(df.loc[df['action']=='BUY', ['timeframe','action','price']],
    ...:               on='timeframe', suffixes=['_sell','_buy'])
    ...:        .eval("result = (price_sell / price_buy - 1) * 100"))
    ...:
Out[83]:
   index timeframe action_sell  result  price_sell action_buy  price_buy
0      1  1 минута        SELL   100.0         200        BUY        100
1      7   1 месяц        SELL    -4.0         240        BUY        250

In [84]: (df[df['action']=='SELL'].reset_index()
    ...:        .merge(df.loc[df['action']=='BUY', ['timeframe','action','price']],
    ...:               on='timeframe', suffixes=['_sell','_buy'])
    ...:        .eval("result = (price_sell / price_buy - 1) * 100")
    ...:        .set_index('index'))
    ...:
Out[84]:
      timeframe action_sell  result  price_sell action_buy  price_buy
index
1      1 минута        SELL   100.0         200        BUY        100
7       1 месяц        SELL    -4.0         240        BUY        250
```

Comment: Спасибо, как всегда отличный, очень полный и подробный ответ!

Comment: @DmitrySharko, всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: Вы для меня снова открываете новые горизонты этого модуля, снова погружаюсь в документацию) Я Вам очень благодарен, рад что есть такой крутой наставник. Без Ваших ответов я бы еще неделю минимум сидел над подобным вопросом, а может и дольше....